# How to write SLD rules with data-defined symbol size and color?

Tags: symbology, sld

I have shapefile with points. They are classified - Graduated colors. I made SLD file with ArcMap2SLDConverter. I have a task to manual edit SLD file to show symbol diameters relating to field Area.

I need to create one rule (for symbol COLOR) relating to one attributes ("Class" column), and second rule (for symbol SIZE) relating to other attributes ("Area" column) for the same geometry. So now I have points with rules for symbol colors, but I don't know how to edit my .sld file to insert rules for symbol size considering they are related to other attribute than those rules for symbol colors.

I don't know how to have two rules relating to two different attribute columns for the same shapefile?

Can someone help me with that task?

Comment: You can edit SLD in Notepad (recommend Notepad++ http://notepad-plus-plus.org/ ) SLD description can be found here - http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-cookbook/index.html

Comment: But I need to create one rule (for symbol COLOR) relating to one attributes ("Class" column), and second rule (for symbol SIZE) relating to other attributes ("Area" column) for the same geometry. So now I have points with rules for symbol colors, but I don't know how to edit my .sdl file to insert rules for symbol size considering they are related to other attribute than those rules for symbol colors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [SLD Cookbook](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-cookbook/index.html) for examples of this. Despite it being on the GeoServer site it is nearly all applicable to all SLD implementations (and the bits that are GeoServer extensions are clearly marked)

Answer (score 2):

I have used a tool called [Atlas Styler](http://en.geopublishing.org/AtlasStyler) in the past to help create some SLD's maybe worth having a look to see if this will help with your rules that you need to implement.

Answer (score 0):

LATITUDE

```
    <!-- Mapping curve definition pairs (input, output) -->
    <ogc:Literal>70</ogc:Literal>  <!--smallest input value -->
    <ogc:Literal>5</ogc:Literal>  <!-- smallest point size -->

    <ogc:Literal>72</ogc:Literal>  <!--largest input value -->
    <ogc:Literal>20</ogc:Literal>  <!-- largest point size -->

</ogc:Function>
```

LATITUDE

```
        <!-- Mapping curve definition pairs (input, output) -->
        <ogc:Literal>70</ogc:Literal>
        <ogc:Literal>#fefeee</ogc:Literal>

        <ogc:Literal>72</ogc:Literal>
        <ogc:Literal>#ff0000</ogc:Literal>

        <!-- Interpolation method -->
        <ogc:Literal>color</ogc:Literal>

        <!-- Interpolation mode - defaults to linear -->
    </ogc:Function>
</CssParameter>
```